# Referencing a class variable from another class via a method

Tags: java, arrays

I'm learning Java, and could use some help here.

At the moment I'm going through Polymorphism, so the code I have has a Dog class, and another class which has a method to add Dog objects to a list (somewhat like an ArrayList).

```
    package chap8;

    /**
     * Created by user1 on 7/11/15.
     */

    class Dog {
        private String name;
        private int age;

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public class MyDogList {

        //array to hold dog objects
        private Dog[] dogs = new Dog[5];

        //int to check index in dog array
        private int nextIndex = 0;

        //add method to add dog objects to dog array
        private void add(Dog d) {
            if(nextIndex < dogs.length) {
                dogs[nextIndex] = d;
                nextIndex++;
                System.out.println("Dog added at position: " + nextIndex);
                System.out.println("Space left for " + (dogs.length - nextIndex) + " more dogs.");
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("No more space to add dogs!");
            }
        }

   private void display() {
        for (int i = 0; i < dogs.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Name of Dog: " + dogs[i].getName());

        }
    }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Dog obj1 = new Dog();
            obj1.setName("Corgi");
            obj1.setAge(2);

            MyDogList dogList = new MyDogList();
            dogList.add(obj1);
            dogList.display();

            Dog obj2 = new Dog();
            obj2.setName("Labrador");
            obj2.setAge(3);

            dogList.add(obj2);

            Dog obj3 = new Dog();
            obj3.setName("Golden Retriever");
            obj3.setAge(5);

            dogList.add(obj3);
        }
    }
```

While the process of adding Dog objects works, what I wanted to have is another method `display`, probably in `class MyDogList` which would display names of all Dog objects in the `dogs` array in `MyDogList` class. But then I realized, if the method just takes in a Dog array, there's no way for it to know the names of individual dog objects in this array.

How should I construct such a method here?

---

EDIT

I realized, from the comments and answers, that I could use the `getter` for the Dog variable `name` to get the name. But when I modify the code (in bold above), I get a `Null Pointer Exception`. What went wrong? Did I try to access an array position before it was set to something?

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7535 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/user1/Documents/idea-IC-141.177.4/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/home/user1/Dropbox/Development/Java/Head First/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/home/user1/Documents/idea-IC-141.177.4/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain chap8.MyDogList
Exception in thread "main" Dog added at position: 1
Space left for 4 more dogs.
Name of Dog: Corgi
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at chap8.MyDogList.display(MyDogList.java:52)
    at chap8.MyDogList.main(MyDogList.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I don't understand. Each `Dog` has `getName`.

Comment: I don't understand, your `display` method looks fine, you just need `list[i].getName()` or even better `Arrays.stream(list).map(Dog::getName).forEach(System.out::println)`. You seem to know how to call methods and how to use arrays - so what is the question exactly?

Comment: Don't completely change your question after you've gotten an answer.

Comment: About your edit. Please look at my answer and think about checking for null. your array is not dynamic, all 5 places are there, but not all are filled with dog objects. I agree with @SotiriosDelimanolis about not changing a question in a way that renders already given answers off topic.

Comment: Understood. Any it wasn't my intention to change the question, or render it off-topic. I wanted to add the part about the exception.

Comment: Edit it in at the end of your question. Don't overwrite. If an answer helped, but caused another problem, ask the author to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this maybe?

```
public void diplay(){
  for (Dog dog : dogs){
    if (dog != null && dog.getName() != null){
      System.out.println("Name of Dog: " + dog.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

Your DogList class already contains the array of dogs. No need to pass a dog array to the display method.

Note also the check for null, since you can't be sure that all array positions are actually filled.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understood, you want something like this in your MyDogList class:

```
public void display(){
    for (int i = 0; i < dogs.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Name of Dog: " + dogs[i].getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: possible NullPointerException. In case dogs[i] is null.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
public void display() {
   for(int i=0; i<nextIndex; i++) {
      if(null != this.dogs[i]) {
         System.out.println(this.dogs[i].getName());
      }
   }
```

Iterate to the last added object and print the name in the Dog object. You don't need to iterate through all array, you only need to go as far as nextIndex is set.

Comment: Would you mind adding an explanation to make people understand what your code does and to improve the quality of your answer?

Comment: possible NullPointerException. In case dogs[i] is null.

Answer (score -2):

**Solution.**

> Added display method. Do put the null check , otherwise nullpointer
>   exception will occur.

```
private void display() {
    for (Dog d : dogs) {
        // null check
        if (d != null) {
            System.out.println("DogName:" + d.getName());
        }
    }
}
```